# Question about RewriteRule and HTTP_HOST server variable

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

In evaluating a rewrite rule that redirects to a specific URL and say the rewrite condition is met, would it be possible to use HTTP_HOST as part of the URL to be redirected to?

Example in question:

```
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpe?g|gif|png|bmp)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/no-leech.jpg [R,NC]
```

The motive behind this question is a desire to create a single htaccess file that would match against an addon domain (on a shared hosting account) and an infinite amount of subdomains below it to prevent hotlinking of images.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `%1` (and `%2`, etc) to access matches in preceding `RewriteCond` statements:

```
RewriteEngine On
# don't redirect no-leech.jpg or we'll end up in a loop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/no-leech.jpg$
# match Host header and store
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpe?g|gif|png|bmp)$ http://%1/no-leech.jpg [R,NC,L]
```

Test:

```
# GET -Sd http://localhost/foo.jpg
GET http://localhost/foo.jpg --> 302 Found
GET http://localhost/no-leech.jpg --> 200 OK
```

And with a different Host header:

```
# GET -SedH 'Host: foo.bar.com' http://localhost/foo.jpg
GET http://localhost/foo.jpg --> 302 Found
GET http://foo.bar.com/no-leech.jpg --> 200 OK
```